# how to use script tag inside of a dynamicly added piece of code for an ad

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamic, ads

i have this card, which includes the ad. I wanted to add this everytime i called my ajax.

what ive tried is just putting the whole card in a

```
document.getElementById("feed_container).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ' <div class="card mt-3 mb-3 bg-dark text-white">
                        <div class="card-body" >
                          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Sponsored Content, sorry :(</h6>
                          <div id="ad-body" class="card-content col d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <script async="async" data-cfasync="false" src="//pl22464107.profitablegatecpm.com/70dc149ec489e883ffe0c36bd73d05d0/invoke.js"></script>
                                <div id="container-70dc149ec489e883ffe0c36bd73d05d0"></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>')

<div class="card mt-3 mb-3 bg-dark text-white">
                        <div class="card-body" >
                          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Sponsored Content, sorry :(</h6>
                          <div id="ad-body" class="card-content col d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <script async="async" data-cfasync="false" src="//pl22464107.profitablegatecpm.com/70dc149ec489e883ffe0c36bd73d05d0/invoke.js"></script>
                                <div id="container-70dc149ec489e883ffe0c36bd73d05d0"></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: When i ran into that, i found the only solution to use `eval`. `eval(document.querySelector('#jsss2').innerHTML);` . For that you do a `<script id=#jsss2>`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: @deEr. you can actually add a script tag as well.

Comment: OK, i see. When i used it, i needed it in an `AJAX` call. Simple load at `HTML` document. But thank you. @LajosArpad

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that adds a script and sets its `src` or `innerHTML`:

```js
function addScript( params, context = document.body ) {
  var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
  if (params.src) s.setAttribute( 'src', src );
  if (params.innerHTML) s.innerHTML = params.innerHTML;
  context.appendChild( s );
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myscript">alert('your script here')</textarea>
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="addScript({innerHTML: document.getElementById('myscript').value})">
```

Comment: Does this work to set the `title`  of a page, after loaded with `AJAX`?

Comment: @deEr. sure. Try `addScript({innerHTML: 'document.querySelector("title").innerText = "something"', document})`

Comment: it is just `document.title=`. Great.

Comment: @deEr. yes, you are correct, I did not know that we can reach it via `document.title` and it's simple than the way I have shown in my previous comment. Thanks!